# Spring MVP Forms overwriting Many to Many ArrayList when updating an object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, forms, hibernate

I have a simple project that has a User model, Sports team model and a Many To Many table where a user can "like" the sports team.

User

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "likes", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
)
private List<Team> teamsLiked;
```

Team

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotBlank
@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String teamName;
@NotBlank
private String city;
private String sport;    
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "likes", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
)
private List<User> likers;
```

My problem is, when I'm using Spring MVC forms for a user to edit a team, upon submission it completely wipes out existing likes on the Team object under likers. On the edit page, I am using @ModelAttribute and pre populating the existing team object, and have tried to put the likers as a hidden attribute so the data will persist, but that throws an error. I've tried on the @PostMapping backend, to set the origin list of likers before re-saving the DB and that's not working either. Besides using Normal HTML forms to update an object, is there a way I can have the list of users who liked a team persist after updating? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a DTO and map that onto an existing entity. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Team.class)
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface TeamDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getTeamName();
    void setTeamName(String teamName);
    String getCity();
    void setCity(String city);
    String getSport();
    void setSport(String sport);
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TeamDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TeamDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TeamDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

And in your case of saving data, you can use the [Spring WebMvc integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#entity-view-deserialization)
that would look something like the following:

```
@Transactional
@PostMapping("/teams")
void save(@RequestBody TeamDto dto){
    repository.save(dto);
}
```